# What is the lifetime of state in React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I cannot find documentation that says how long a state will hold its values.
I read that if a page refreshes, then the state will be lost, but what about when redirecting to another component/page? Will the state be lost if I redirect from one component to another?

Or does the state last until the user physically refreshes the page?

Comment: It will last until the component that uses `Provider` unmounts. When that event happens is based on implementation. If your `Provider` is at the top level of your app - then it will last until the page is refreshed or closed. If you use the provider in a lower component that can be unmounted on a page change, then it will be lost when that component unmounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- your state is lost when the page is refreshed (i.e. when the component is unmounted)
- when you navigate to another component/page, your state is NOT lost. With react router navigations and react re-renders, the state is not lost.
- If you want to retain state after page refresh then you need to store your state in localStorage & retain the state upon component mount.